# How to delete certain item(s) returned by FindExternalEvaluators[]?

Tags: external-calls, python

I have tried `UnregisterExternalEvaluator` only to find that the item's state "Registered", changed from `True` to `False`. But I want that item to disappear from the results given by `FindExternalEvaluators`.

[image]

Well, as shown in the figure above, because the version 3.6.3 is actually no longer existing, I want that somehow *Mathematica* does not know that information any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just evaluate these commands:

```
ExternalEvaluate; (* trigger autoloading *)
ExternalEvaluate\`Private\`resetCache[]
```

[See this post for more details](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167539/findexternalevaluatorspython-gives-me-an-uninstalled-version-of-python)

Comment: Though it completely deletes all.

Comment: If this really completes all as commented this warning definitely needs to be included in the answer. I did not read the comment before running. Although actually for me it did not run at all. `ExternalEvaluate\`Private\`resetCache[] ` wasn't valid code.