# Removing notebook cache from ExternalEvaluate

Tags: python, external-calls, caching

### Question

While working with Python's `ExternalEvaluate` the intermediate calculation results with Python are stored in the notebook. (`ExternalEvaluate` seems to cache evaluation results.)

How can I remove that cached data from the notebook?
(Say, before sharing with others.)

(I tried the commands [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167809/34008) and others, without success...)

---

### Code to reproduce "caching effect"

#### 1) Make a notebook

Create/enter the following Python cells:

```
samples=[]
samples.append("".join(["a","B","C","73","e"][1:4]))
len(samples)
```

```
[len(x) for x in samples]
```

```
def some_func(x):
    return x / 100
```

```
some_func("yyu")
```

And save the corresponding notebook.

You should get something like this:

[image]

#### 2) Find cached values

Open the notebook as text or in a text editor and search for the string "BC73".

*(You should be able to find it, but I do not think one should, or at least, there should be a way to opt out.)*

You can also find peculiar execution data or paths of your environment.

---

### Additional comments

So, I can answer my question as:

> Remove failure objects of Python external evaluations.

But I am curious are there any better and/or more "bureaucratic" solutions.

The reason I am making "all that fuzz" is because in the way described above one can inadvertently *and* easily share certain access and/or private information.

(In my case, accessing certain cloud services.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "caching intermediate calculation results"? For example, if I do some simple `ExternalEvalute` with python, there seems to be no sign of any caching [in the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXKq0.png). It would help if you give a concrete example of how to reproduce your issue ...

Comment: I cannot see any cached results in my notebook in which I used python. Can you post what is in your notebook that you think is cache produced by `ExternalEvaluate`?

Comment: @azerbajdzan  and Domen -- Thank you for your comments! You are right -- using regular, non-problematic Python code does not produce the caching effects I observed. I am going to explain in more detail in a post.

Comment: I do not think it is any cache. It is simply the output cell produced by evaluating python code. when you delete the output cell and save notebook again the thing you claim is cache disappear from the file.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Right. (And I suggested/mentioned that in my question edit.) The question is: Is there a better way of doing it? (Again, see my question edit.)

Comment: I do not think there is any better way than deleting cells that you do not want to appear in the notebook.

Comment: @Anton Antonov: Maybe I found a way to automatize it... see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This delete all cells in the notebook that contain `"Failure"`. To prevent the code to delete itself I had to write `"Failure"` as `"Fail" <> "ure"` otherwise also this cell would be deleted.

```
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "Fail" <> "ure", All, CellContents]
NotebookDelete[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

Maybe you can run it as last cell code also with saving notebook like this:

```
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "Fail" <> "ure", All, CellContents]
NotebookDelete[EvaluationNotebook[]]
NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

Or instead of `"Failure"` you can use `"PythonError"` in the form `"Python"<>"Error"` to be more specific since `Failure` is used by Mathematica and it could lead to deleting unwanted cells.

Comment: Agreed, using "PythonError" is better.

Comment: Thank you for your post.